# Compare points of a circle in canvas with a drawing made in canvas by the user

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, coordinates, geometry

I have to make a code that starts from a *circle in canvas*, the user can draw on it and compare the points of the correct circle with the one that the user has drawn on top. Thus deducing the percentage of failure or success that the user has had.

**That's how I keep the coordinates of the correct circle.**

```
var centerX=200;
var centerY=200;
var radius=70;

// array save circlePoints
var points=[];

for(var degree=0;degree<360;degree++){
    var radians = degree * Math.PI/180;
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians);
    points.push({x:x,y:y});
}
```

**That's how the user can draw on canvas and I save this coordinates:**

```
function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        arrayCoordenadas.push({currX:currX,currY:currY});

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            arrayCoordenadas.push({currX:currX,currY:currY});
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the way I save the coordinates when I draw is the right one, nor do I know how to compare both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that an easier way to look up your coordinates is to store your initial circle values in an object where each value of `x` has an array of `y` values associated with it. The example here shows how to check each user point to see if it matches a point on the circle.

```js
var centerX=200;
var centerY=200;
var radius=70;

// array save circlePoints
  //set to object instead, for each X value store an array of Y values that correspond.
  //this makes checking a user point easier
var points = {};

for(var degree=0;degree<360;degree++){
    var radians = degree * Math.PI/180;
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians);
    
    if(!points[x]) points[x] = [] //if the array for point x doesn't exist, create it
    points[x].push(y) //push the y value into the array for the x value
}


function isPointOnCircle(x,y){
  return !!points[x] && points[x].indexOf(y) > -1
}


var userPoints = [
  [270,200],
  [130,50],
  [200,270],
  [100,200]
]

userPoints.forEach(point => {
  console.log(isPointOnCircle(...point))
})
```